# Should I use Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java

i know a similar question has been asked before but, my question is somewhat different. I have been learning C# for a few years but nothing in game making, more like applications and web like programs. I have seen many say java is a program that is not used as much now, but my favorite games like Minecraft and Runescape are both java games. My idea for the game would be something that opens like minecraft with a splash screen then a interactive screen that lets you do things and enter a saved game or make a new one. I see a lot of java games and have never heard of any large game being in C# yet people have told me don't use/learn java. Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: Technology or language choice questions are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to choose a language just based on the popularity of some titles that have been made with them? Sure, Minecraft was made in Java. Well, [Terraria](http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600/) (over one million copies sold), [Bastion](http://store.steampowered.com/app/107100) (a gazillion awards last year), and [Magicka](http://store.steampowered.com/app/42910) among others, were made in C#. Does it matter? I really don't think so.

Furthermore if you already have a few years of experience with C#, I don't see any advantages in changing over to Java. And by the way, if you decide to use C# and want to take advantage of modern hardware features, you could look into using something like [SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/) for instance. Otherwise, use XNA or keep a close eye on the [ANX framework](http://anxframework.codeplex.com/) which is currently under development.